# OpenVPN with PAM with systemd and SELinux

Tags: centos, openvpn, systemd, pam, selinux

I am trying to set up an OpenVPN (2.4.9) server with PAM login on CentOS 8.2 and I am facing some strange issues.
Specifically, i can successfully athenticate if I start the server with the ExecStart command specified in the systemd unit file

`sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --status /home/XXX/openvpn.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --cipher AES-256-GCM --ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-CBC:BF-CBC --config server.conf`

However, if I start the server via systemd

`sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server`

I see the following authentication error in my openvpn log

```
AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: received command code: 0
AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: USER: XXXX
AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: my_conv[0] query='Password: ' style=1
AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: user 'XXXX' failed to authenticate: Authentication failure
2.204.43.58:49048 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
2.204.43.58:49048 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so
2.204.43.58:49048 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
```

Is there anyone who knows what the issue might be? I must be something about the additional systemd configuration, or am I wrong?

Cheers!

Tobias

The systemd-unit file `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service` looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service for %I
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/server
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status %t/openvpn-server/status-%i.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --cipher AES-256-GCM --ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-CBC:BF-CBC --config %i.conf
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
KillMode=process
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is my openvpn server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/3/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/3/pki/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/3/pki/private/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/3/pki/dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-GCM
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 6
plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
username-as-common-name
```

And here my openvpn Pam file

```
auth required pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup vpnlogin
auth substack system-auth
auth include postlogin
account required pam_nologin.so
account include system-auth
password include system-auth
session required pam_selinux.so close
session required pam_loginuid.so
session optional pam_console.so
session required pam_selinux.so open
session required pam_namespace.so
session optional pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session include system-auth
session include postlogin
-session optional pam_ck_connector.so
```

Auth logs at /var/log/secure looks as follows:

```
Jul 15 17:23:51 YYYY openvpn[9730]: pam_succeed_if(openvpn2:auth): requirement "user ingroup vpnlogin" was met by user "XXXX"
Jul 15 17:23:51 YYYY unix_chkpwd[9747]: check pass; user unknown
Jul 15 17:23:51 YYYY unix_chkpwd[9748]: check pass; user unknown
Jul 15 17:23:51 YYYY unix_chkpwd[9748]: password check failed for user (XXXX)
Jul 15 17:23:51 YYYY openvpn[9730]: pam_unix(openvpn2:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=XXXX
```

The audit log at /var/log/audit/audit.log looks as follows:

```
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1594833821.311:12583): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=openvpn-server@server comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'^]UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1594833821.395:12584): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=NetworkManager dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'^]UID="root" AUID="unset" 
type=AVC msg=audit(1594833831.005:12585): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=9747 comm="unix_chkpwd" capability=1  scontext=system_u:system_r:chkpwd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:chkpwd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1594833831.007:12586): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=9748 comm="unix_chkpwd" capability=1  scontext=system_u:system_r:chkpwd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:chkpwd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1594833831.008:12587): pid=9730 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=? acct="XXXX" exe="/usr/sbin/openvpn" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'^]UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1594833831.255:12588): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=NetworkManager dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'^]UID="root" AUID="unset"
```

Comment: Well, this shouldn't be happening. `chkpwd_t` should already have `dac_read_search` which is sufficient for reading `/etc/shadow`. It's [probably a spurious message](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/77140.html) that can be ignored, but it's still failing when it shouldn't be.

Comment: OK, I looked up unit file for the systemd service and ran the ExecStart command as root.  Again, login works flawlessly. Makes me think that this might have something to do with the additional specifications of the service. Might this have something to do with the CapabilityBoudaries? I adjusted the answer to include the unitfile. This guy here [https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/f9pp0c/openvpn_centos8_local_login/] seems to have the same problem

Comment: The unit looks the same as shipped by the distro. So I don't think the problem is there. I'm still thinking about this but I use certificates with OpenVPN so I wouldn't run into this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resolution

I don't know if this is the best solution, but the issue got resolved when I replaced `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` by `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` in the `CapabilityBoundingSet` of `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service`.
My understanding is that from a security standpoint this might be preferable anyway.

**CAVEAT**: Although for my configuration this did not raise any issues and everything seems to run smoothly, it might make problems for other configurations as the openvpn unit runs with fewer privileges.

## What might be going on

I assume that `unix_chkpwd` gets executed with the capabilities of the calling process, which would be `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`. However, since `unix_chkpwd` does not need this access level, it gets denied by SELinux and fails to open `/etc/shadow`. If anyone with a deeper understanding of systemd/pam/SELinux knows more I would be glad to be corrected.

Comment: This was driving me batty. Thank you so much for a fix. I was going to try and disable selinux entirely since it would connect with it off. This allows me to keep it on. Thank you so much.